# Segfault when accessing central widget from slot

Tags: c++, qt, access-violation

I'm creating a simple desktop app with a single window and a navigation based on `QStackedWidget` as central widget.

Upon starting, the application adds a widget in the `QStackedWidget` and other widgets are added after user interaction. Unfortunately simply trying to access the `QStackedWidget` from a widget's slot causes a segfault.

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  ui->centralWidget->addWidget(new LoginPage(this)); // centralWidget = QStackedWidget
}

void MainWindow::onLoginSuccess()
{
  qDebug() << ui->centralWidget;
}
```

**LoginPage.cpp slot**

```
void LoginPage::on_loginButton_clicked()
{
  // Check stuff and all

  ((MainWindow*)parent())->onLoginSuccess();
}
```

The simple debug in `onLoginSuccess()` results in this error:

> Exception at 0x760f92a7, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x0, flags=0x0 (first chance)

I have no trouble updating other UI elements from the slot, so I don't know what's wrong here.

Comment: It seems that parent() is null and you are not checking for that. Is your constructor for LoginPage correctly handling the parent parameter?

Comment: Also I would use a signal / slot for this. I mean connect on_loginButton_clicked to MainWindow::onLoginSuccess() instead of a direct call.

Comment: parent isn't null, calling the method doesn't fail if I simply debug a string or anything else. As for using signal/slot this would mean putting most of the logic in the `MainWindow` which doesn't really make sense...

Comment: The signal slot would be a single connect in your constructor for LoginPage.

Comment: ***parent isn't null*** Something is null then. I mean `read access violation at: 0x0` means you are using a null pointer.

Comment: BTW, if you had some logic in on_loginButton_clicked() you could add a signal to LoginPage and emit that after your logic. And just connect to the parent using this new signal.

Comment: @jturcotte 's answer was the right one, but using signal/slots sounds like a nicer solution than casting the parent and calling the method, thanks

Comment: Don't use C-style casts. Use [`qobject_cast`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) instead and check if the object is valid in these kind of situations. But the solution here is definitely to use signals and slots as drescherjm suggested. But instead of connecting the signal inside the `LoginPage` constructor, do it inside the `MainWnidow` class. This is where you create the `LoginPage` object, and `LoginPage` should know nothing about `MainWindow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `MainWindow::MainWindow`:

```
  ui->centralWidget->addWidget(new LoginPage(this)); // centralWidget = QStackedWidget
```

[addWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#addWidget) will reparent your LoginPage. So parent() is actually a QStackedWidget* and your MainWindow* cast is wrong in on_loginButton_clicked.

Comment: @Jukurrpa I told you absolutely same thing and you said that I'm not right and I deleted answer. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @Chernobyl, I must have misunderstood your answer then... Sorry. The oddity is that putting a simple debug line in `onLoginSuccess()` didn't cause any error, so I thought the parent was right at that time.